# Push Notification - App Badge Icon

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

After receiving push notification app icon not display badge.

In setting notification is on, badge app icon is on.

any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the badge explicitly when you are pushing a Notification.

If you fail to provide a badge it wil be cleared and you won't see a badge.

The message you send needs to look like this

```
{
    "aps":
    {
        "alert":
        {
            "action-loc-key": "Open",
            "body": "Hello, world!"
        },
        "badge": 2
    }
}
```

without the `"badge": 2` the badge is cleared.